# What is the url to a Facebook open graph post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Given a post id returned by a graph search, for example: 186173001411937

is there a url to link to the post in facebook?
The following url does not work:
http://www.facebook.com/post.php?id=186173001411937

Answer (score 49):

I found out, for a graph id 1099696306_140549259338782 the links is build like this:
http://www.facebook.com/1099696306/posts/140549259338782

Comment: @corrego you click the checkmark right under the up/down buttons next to the answer.

Comment: The user has to be logged in to see this post, is it possible for public to see this post?

Comment: @corrego this does not work 100% of the time. I have found that the schema for older posts is different. See this bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/683573291807160/ use the `permalink_url` field instead.

Answer (score 22):

Honestly, the simplest way I've found to do this is just:

```
"http://www.facebook.com/" + postId
```

Where `postId` is just the straight id of the post (186173001411937), not the userid_postid variant.

Comment: This won't work for user-posts on pages, the solution by @user580602 however covers this case.

Comment: The user has to be logged in to see this post, is it possible for public to see this post?

Comment: This does not work in all cases. For me it fails a majority of the time use the `permalink_url` field instead

Comment: Yeah I don't really recommend this method anymore. I found it by experimentation and have never seen it documented so it's probably not the best option if you can find a more reliable way.

Answer (score 6):

with the graph api v2.5 you can use the permalink_url field of the the posts object.

i.e.:

```
www.facebook.com/v2.5/{pagename}/?fields=posts{permalink_url,message,story,created_time,id}
```

will return

```
"posts": {
   "data": [
   {
    "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/etsmtl/posts/10153868925494376",
    "message": "Le Club Cedille organise le prochain Linux-Meetup ce soir à l'ÉTS. Au programme : conférence de James Shubin, ingénieur logiciel sénior chez Red Hat.",
    "created_time": "2016-03-01T15:23:11+0000",
    "id": "8632204375_10153868925494376"
   }, ... }
```

Comment: This seems to be the best answer; however, as far as I know it is not in the docs. In this bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/683573291807160/ the Facebook engineer said it will be the change log if it is changed.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to a public facing page post take the **Id** returned from the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) e.g. **12345678_12345678** and append it to *facebook.com* e.g. https://www.facebook.com/12345678_12345678. The post is also *highlighted* as you access the page.

Comment: Fantastic, dead-simple solution.  Thank you very much.  Facebook needs to do a better job documenting their APIs if they expect the world to use them.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public <T>getPagePosts(string pageId, string access_token, int limit)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://graph.facebook.com");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            var fields = "posts{permalink_url,picture,message,story,created_time,id}";
            request.Resource = "{version}/{object_id}/";
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.JsonSerializer.ContentType = "application/json;";
            request.AddParameter("access_token", access_token);
            request.AddParameter("version", "v2.10", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
            request.AddParameter("object_id", pageId, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
            request.AddParameter("limit", limit);
            request.AddParameter("fields", fields);
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);
            return result;
        }
```